# Hide basic auth credentials in Javascript client

Tags: javascript, api, security, client, basic-authentication

I need to make from my client side javascript code an ajax request posting some data to the backend with jQuery.

```
$.ajax({...});
```

The Javascript code can be embedded by various client so I enabled `CORS` on my backend and the requests go fine.
The backend is protected by an `Basic Auth` and the auth header is stored in the javascript client.

How can I protect my backend so only my client can post data and prevent any other people from doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store secrets in JavaScript. There's no way you can hold on to a username and password without at least the user being able to get to them (F12 debugging tools). Even if were to use [JavaScript encryption](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES), you'd still need to store the secret key somewhere on the client where it can easily be discovered.

And even if you trust the user, [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks may leak this username and password info to an attacker.

That's why OAuth 2.0 uses short lived access tokens in an [implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) to deal with public clients.